# wordpress images not being indexed on google search console

Tags: wordpress, indexing, google-search-console

[this is the search console view of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Bib.png)

it's for 1 week we launched and submitted our web domain on google by yet just 15 images out of total 59 images are indexed or crawled by google. so now we have gotten frustrated by the issue this is while 70 out total 77 submitted webpages have been indexed by google. so now we request you team to provide us the solution. 
Thanks a lot in advance for you taking time on the issue
Ramin
Content Mamager
JMR

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en refer the article and get an idea about how google CRAWL your website

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to install an SEO plugin like `Yoast SEO`.

From the dashboard, you need to enable the Sitemap from SEO Plugin for `media attachments, post, pages, categories, tags.`

Now in your google webmaster settings submit the sitemap link created.

You can submit the one file that is index file of sitemap or you can submit the different listed files in that index, the result is the same.

Google will index your sitemap slowly but it will.

[Reference](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-images-in-a-WordPress-blog-not-indexed-by-Google)